# Sigma Notation Skipping Certain Values

Tags: measure-theory, summation

I would like to sum all cells of a two dimensional matrix while skipping the diagonal cells. Please help me to write this in sigma notation. I think it should be something similar to the following:

Let $x$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.

Let $x_{ij}$ be the value in row $i$ and column $j$.

$\displaystyle y = \sum_{i \neq j}^n x_{ij}$

Is that correct or should there be something else? Thanks in advance.

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: You can even use just $\displaystyle \sum_{i\neq j} x_{ij}$ since it would be implicit that $i$ and $j$ would assume all other legal values.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry to have answered my own question, but I needed confirmation.